# Xcode, iphone - Make image animation move in specific direction 

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, animation

I'm creating an animated ball which should move across the screen. I want to make it move towards the center of the screen as if it is attracted by the center. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; //starting Animation

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
[UIView setAnimationRrepeatAutoreverses:YES];

CGPoint position = 200.0f;
position.y = 200.0f;
position.x = 150.0f;
img.center = position;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

If it is cocos2d,You can use Move method,

```
id move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(160,240);
[sprite runAction:move];
```

Comment: `CGPoint position = 200.0f;` isn't right, right?  Also, don't you need `CGPointMake(160.0f, 240.0f)` for the center?

Comment: yeah sorry....there is a two points....

Answer (score 1):

```
 image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x + 10, image.center.y);
```