# ImageArray Assignment to single Image

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I am new to iphone development. I have an Image Array as follows.

```
NSArray *eyeFrames = [NSArray array];

eyeFrames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"eyes1-open.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"eyes3-half.png"],
                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"eyes2-empty.png"],
                 nil];
```

I have an ImageView as follows

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *eyesImage;
```

Now I want to assign this array of Images to my ImageView .

What i tried so far is as follows:

```
eyesImage.animationImages = eyeFrames;
```

But it doesn't seem to provide the expected result.Can anyone tell me how to do it ?

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Did you try like this IBOutlet UIImageView *eyesImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:(UIImage *) [eyeFrames objectAtIndex:1]] ;

Comment: No . I didn't try this. I will try it once.

Comment: please let me know if it works...if it works I can paste it as answer..

Comment: yea . I will let you know if it works.

Comment: I didn't get the result . Now I am thinking that , is it possible to assign multiple images to the single ImageView.I don't think it is possible after giving  a lot of try.

Comment: No see my answer you are trying to do some thing like image slider right...  you can follow my code answer to do it.  In my answer 0.9 will be too fast you have to adjust to get the desired speed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For animating series of images like image slider following is the code:

```
NSArray *myImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"eyes1-open.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"eyes3-half.png"],
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"eyes2-empty.png"],                             
                             nil];

        eyesImage.animationImages = myImages;
        eyesImage.animationDuration = 0.9; // seconds
        eyesImage.animationRepeatCount = 1; // 0 = loops forever
        [eyesImage startAnimating];

        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

For accessing the file from array and set to Image view you have to do like this

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *eyesImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:(UIImage *) [eyeFrames objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks,the first part worked for me . The second one I will try later

Comment: I need one more help. Is it possible to specify the animation distance  .i.e, I want  my images to be moved upwards one after another after some time.

Comment: and IBOutlet UIImageView *eyesImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:(UIImage *) [eyeFrames objectAtIndex:1]]; doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I have not done anything like that yet..  however these links could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/1672489/763747 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680044/763747  what you have to try is you can set Y point to 0 and move up some point like 100 inside the start animation..  I can try that tomorrow and try to update the answer Raj...:)

Comment: That is for getting individual image inside the image view..  It will not work with animation..

Comment: My requirement is , I have an array of 5 images and single ImageView outlet,which I have put in my nib. Now  after assigning,I want these images to move upward one after another through animation.Hope I am clear

Comment: all the links specify , animation of a single image ,which I achieved quiet easily . No link specifies how to animate an array of images . Anyways will be waiting for your update tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

Don`t forget to 
set "animationDuration" and "animationRepeatCount" properties, then call  "startAnimating"

```
eyesImage.animationDuration=0.1; //seconds
eyesImage.animationRepeatCount=2; 
[eyesImage startAnimating];
```